# Autopopulate select box based on previous checkbox selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to create a form with two questions, where the answers from the first question (checkboxes) become the selections for the second question (select boxes). Here are the two questions:

Question 1: At which colleges have you played baseball? (checkboxes)
Question 2: Of these schools, which baseball field/stadium did you like best? (select box)

The answers from the first question would need to automatically populate the select field.

It seems the first step would be to create an array based on the answers from Question 1. Here's what I have so far. This script writes the answers to the page in real-time. My thought here was to make sure I'm capturing the answers. The problem I'm having is how to construct the second question based on the answers from the first.

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="University of Alabama" id="University of Alabama">
  <label for="ch1">University of Alabama</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Florida" id="University of Florida">
  <label for="ch2">University of Florida</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="Georgia" id="University of Georgia">
  <label for="ch3">University of Georgia</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="University of North Carolina" id="University of North Carolina">
  <label for="ch4">University of North Carolina</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="University of South Carolina" id="University of South Carolina">
  <label for="ch4">University of South Carolina</label>
</form>

<p><b>Results:</b> <span id="results"></span></p>

<script>
  function showValues() {
    var fields = $( ":input" ).serializeArray();
    $( "#results" ).empty();
    jQuery.each( fields, function( i, field ) {
      $( "#results" ).append( field.value + " " );
    });
  }

  $( ":checkbox, :radio" ).click( showValues );
  $( "select" ).change( showValues );
  showValues();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick note -- I recommend using an `array` name for your checkbox inputs, like so:

```
<input name="check[]" value="..." />
```

That being said, here's a quick and dirty solution that may kick you off in the right direction. You can just call `showValues()` with whatever handler you'd like.

```
// Here's what your usage might look like:
$("#my_button").on('click', showValues);
// or for updates in 'real-time'...
$("input[name='check[]']").on('click', showValues);

function showValues() {
    var schools = [];
    var checked = $("input[name='check[]']:checked");
    $.each(checked, function (_, el) {
        schools.push(el.value);
    });

    if (schools.length > 0) {
        var fav_select = $('<div id="favorite_school_box"><label for="favorite_school">Which stadium was your favorite?</label></div>');
        var fav_list = $('<select name="favorite_school"></select');
        $.each(schools, function (_, school) {
            fav_list.append('<option value="' + school + '">' + school + '</option>');
        });
        fav_select.append(fav_list);
        if ($("#favorite_school_box").length <= 0) {
            $("body").append(fav_select);
        } else {
            $("#favorite_school_box").replaceWith(fav_select);
        }
    }
    else {
        alert('Please make a selection.');
    }
}
```

Note -- keep in mind this function is not very abstracted and, given a situation where you had 50 or 100 or 1,000 questions depending on answers from previous questions, this wouldn't be a sufficient solution. I just wanted to show how you might accomplish this literally, and give you a starting point for additional functions/better functions in the future.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Thankfully the first question will only include 10 choices, so this approach just might work. I'm trying to recreate this in JSFiddle and am struggling.

Comment: Did you rename your check inputs from `check` to `check[]`?